# Compare double values within 2 dimensional arrays in Java

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, compare, double

I have a two dimensional array and it has words and double values in string format.

In each array of two dimensional array last index is a double value however except that values every 2 or 3 arrays are similar.

I need to find that similar arrays and find the one with minimum double value.

Here is my array:

```
[

  [anestol, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 4.20], 
  [anestol, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 4.00], 
  [zimaks, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 11.26], 
  [duphalac, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 11.80], 
  [duphalac, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 12.80]

]
```

For instance in first and second element are similar except 4.20 and 4.00. How can I extract the one with value 4.00 from there and the same things for others?

My wish output is like that:

```
[

  [anestol, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 4.00], 
  [zimaks, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 11.26], 
  [duphalac, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 11.80], 

]
```

Comment: can you please also post your wishes out put. which gives better understanding what you want.

Comment: your inner array looks like it could be replaced by object, any reason why you using array instead?

Comment: vishal gajera  this array and its elements can be also more or less, actually it is part of a program.So that for instance there can be 4-5 similar anestol elements or even 10 duphacal elements and etc.So i need take every one of them with minimum double value.I am thinking extract them and add them to list then convert it to new array.My wished output is like that for instance : <br> [

  [anestol, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 4.00], 
  [zimaks, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 11.26], 
  [duphalac, es, 01.01.2016, 31.12.2016, 11.80], 
 

]

Comment: user902383 i am new at Java that is why.And also in programming

Answer (score 0):

Create class that will contains fields whith values of your arrays. You'll get 5 instances of your class.
Implement interface Comparable.
Put all instances into list or array. 
In for-each constraction compare class instances and get one which you are looking for.
In for-each circle put instanses into Set. Before put into Set, check does enather version of instance is presents in Set. If presents then compare their double values